# How to show comments and replycomments in laravel

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I don't know how to show comments and replycomments in my post page. My comments table contains id, sender_id, replyer_id, reply_id, comment_text.

CommentController returns a comment object. In Post.blade.php, how do I write a foreach loop or loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller code must be similar to this:

```
public function index() 
{
    $comments = Comment::with(['sender', 'other-relation'])->get();
    return view('comments.index', compact('comments'));
}
```

and your blade code must be similar to this:

```
<ul>
@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <li>{{ $comment->comment_text }}</li>
    @if ($comment->sender) // or other relation 
        <a> {{$comment->sender->name}}<a> // relation name and column name must be fix yourself
    @endif
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Excuse me, my comment table has id, user_id, post_id, reply_id, comment_text field. Is controller code for show comment and replys, Comment::with(['id','reply_id'])->get();   ?                 and when run it display error from model. Why?

Comment: Are you defined in Comment model relations, and can you add it question??

Comment: No , how can do it?

Comment: see docs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent)

Comment: Add `Comment` and `Replycomment` models

Comment: I have one table for comment and replycomment,, why create 2 seprate model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174571/discussion-between-parham-nikdouz-and-davit).

Answer (score 1):

Inside blade file:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($comments as $comment)
    <li>{{ $comment->comment_text }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: I have comments and reply comment in table, how to show each replycomments bottom of comment?

Comment: i you know how to loop, then inside controller define this variable.
`$comments = Comment::with(['Sender', 'Replyer', 'Reply'])->get(); `
else die-dump the above, you will understand.

To access the sender (inside loop):
$comment->sender->FIELDNAME